# How to add 2 different classes using if in jquery

Tags: jquery

How to add 2 different classes using jquery?

I have this code:

```
<div id="divprincipal" class="divprincipal">
    <div id="div1" class="max"></div>
</div>

var clase1 = $('#hola').attr('class');
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#hola").click(function () {
        $("#divprincipal").animate({
            height: "30px"
        }, 1000);
        $("#hola").addClass("min");
        alert(clase1);
        if (clase1 == "min") {
            $("#divprincipal").animate({
                height: "200px"
            }, 1000);
            $("#hola").addClass("max");
            alert(clase1);
        }
    });
});
```

I added an alert to know what's the current class and i keep returning the same class

Comment: You are changing the jQuery element, but not `clase1` that's why

Comment: You probably want to use `.hasClass` for the test: http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Comment: Why do you want to add the class `min` to `#hola` and then *immediately* test if it's there?

Comment: Btw, if you want to toggle between two classes you could use `.toggleClass('min max');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clase1` is defined prior to the change, and is not a live collection (such as a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)) as some reference values in javascript will be. It is just a primitive string.

In order to determine if that class is present, you will need to check again instead of referencing the stored value

```
var clase1 = $('#hola').attr('class');
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#hola").click(function(){
  $("#divprincipal").animate({ height:"30px"}, 1000);
  $("#hola").addClass("min");
  clase1 = $('#hola').attr('class');
  alert(clase1);
    if (clase1=="min"){
        $("#divprincipal").animate({ height:"200px"}, 1000);
        $("#hola").addClass("max");
        alert(clase1);
    }
 });
});
```

Moreover, you may wish to also use jQuery to detect if this class is present instead of looking to see if the whole class name is the same as "min" using `hasClass`.

```
if( $('#hola').hasClass('min') )
{
 //conditional code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add two classes to same element yo need to do this:

> $("#hola").addClass("max min");

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but that's not was i was looking for. I appreciate your help tho.